# Running Checks on all files in all subdirectories

Tags: linux, bash

I have looked through MANY questions asked and none of the solutions are working for me. 
I want to run an md5sum check on all files in all subdirectories from that specified in cd [directory].
Example:

```
cd [directory]

for f in *; do 
    if [[ -f "$f" ]]; then
        (md5sum -- "$f" > "md5_${f}") 
    fi
done
```

Thanks to a commentor, I understood my initial error which took my command as a directory instead of running it.

The issue now is that it runs successfully in the first directory it is looking at, but does not run correctly in sub-directories.

Per comment

```
find . - type f ! - name /'md5_*' -execdir sh -c /
    for f; do
         b="$(basename "$f")";
         [ ! -e "md5_$b" ] && md5sum "$b" > "md5$b"
    done
```

output 
find: paths must precede expression: -
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]

Comment: Maybe replace `( MY COMMAND )` by `( ./PATH/TO/MY/COMMAND )`?

Comment: So, I cd to the directory I want. the  (My Command) Is a check that I want run on all files in all sub-directories.

Comment: Is your command a program or script you have written? Or is it a program in one of the directories already added to your _path_ environment variable?

Comment: It is a one line command that can be executed on a single file. (md5sum -- "$file" > "md5_${file}")

Comment: If you want md5sum to be feed by stdin (hence the "--"), what's $file purpose there before the GT angle?

Comment: Please use the body of your question to describe what you want to do and exactly what's happening (instead). The example you found executes one command per directory (without passing in that directory name). If you "want to run on all files in all sub-directories", then people might have an answer that looks very different from what you have.

Comment: @uprego I see what I did.... take a look at my edit? thanks for making me look at it twice.

Comment: You want to check or to compute the hash? if you want to compute it, it is best to keep all the hashes in the same file, because you can check a whole tree with just the that output file and a single `md5sum -c` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with one `find` command:

```
find . -type f ! -name 'md5_*' -execdir sh -c \
  'for f; do
     b="$(basename "$f")"
     [ ! -e "md5_$b" ] || [ "$b" -nt "md5_$b" ] && md5sum "$b" >  "md5_$b"
   done' sh {} +
```

The `! -name 'md5_*` option excludes md5_* files, and the `-execdir` option causes find to cd to each directory containing files, and then running the `sh -c '....'` command in it.   It runs as few `sh -c ...` commands per directory as possible (usually only one, depending on the maximum command line limit on your system - typically 2MB or more these days).

The `[ ! -e "md5_$b" ] || [ "$b" -nt "md5_$b" ]` test in the shell script ensures that `md5sum` is only run for files where either the `md5_` file does not exist or if the file is newer than its `md5_` file.

---

If you wanted to have only one `md5sums.txt` file in each directory, it would be simpler:

```
find . -type f ! -name 'md5sums.txt' -execdir sh -c \
  'md5sum "$@" >md5sums.txt' sh {} +
```

and even simpler if you wanted just one `md5sums.txt` file listing all files in all subdirectories:

```
rm -f md5sums.txt
find . -type f -exec md5sum {} + >> md5sums.txt
```

---

This version should work with busybox's version of `find`, and maybe other minimalist versions:

```
find . -type f ! -name 'md5_*' -exec sh -c \
  'for f; do
     cd "$(dirname "$f")"
     b="$(basename "$f")"
     [ ! -e "md5_$b" ] || [ "$b" -nt "md5_$b" ] && md5sum "$b" >  "md5_$b"
     cd - >/dev/null
   done' sh {} +
```

It'll run a bit slower because it has to do the directory changing in the shell script...and it has to do `cd` twice for every file, rather than just once per directory.

I would have used `pushd` and `popd` to change directories, but if you're running busybox find or similar, you're probably also running a minimalist `sh` like `dash`.

Comment: btw, do you need one md5_ file per filename?  why not just have a single `md5sums.txt` file in each directory?

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need and very well described. It is a req to have a file per file. otherwise I would agree with you for simplicity. I'm just getting an error on the 'for' box. That I'm looking at now.

Comment: This might be exactly what I want but I'm getting 2 separate errors. One that the last part after done is breaking the parse. the other that find: paths must precede expression: =
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]

Comment: that's strange.  I did test that before posting it.  are you still having problems with this?  did you copy-paste this or type it?

Comment: Yes I'm still having the issue. I've gone over it probably 30 times and don't see a difference. It looked like it might be not having quotes around the "name" but? Unsure.

Comment: 1. are you running busybox or similar? on some tiny distro?   2. you typed `-name`, not just `name` right?  3. the quotes around `'md5_*'` are necessary, to make sure the shell doesn't expand it if there are any md5_* files in the current directory.

Comment: I get a similar error message when I run it with `busybox find ....` (but complaining about the -execdir option not being recognized).   Looks like that's what your version of find is.  Which linux distribution are you running?  can you install the GNU `findutils` package?

Comment: I'm running it on an active *staging* area.  yea I have -name. and quotes.

Comment: what's an "active staging area"?  what version of find is available in that environment?  what do you get if you run `find --version`?  do you get about 7 lines of version and licensing message starting with `find (GNU findutils)` or an error message (perhaps mentioning busybox or tinybox) and brief usage info? or something else?

Comment: find (GNU findutils) 4.5.11
Just a fancy way of saying it's got everything I need and replicates where it will be working on.

Comment: i'm running GNU find 4.6.0.235-f254 but the find command above should run with any almost any version of GNU find.   Can you copy and paste the **exact** find command you're running into your question?   and the **exact** output?

Comment: Added requested. After I messed up and somehow edited your answer? I don't think the person asking the question should be allowed to edit answers...

Comment: anyone with sufficient rep can edit an answer or a question.  it then has to be approved (either by the author of the Q or A, or by vote).  If you have lots of reputation on the site, you can make edits without approval.   BTW, edits can always be rolled back.

Comment: anyway, it looks like you're only running the first line of the command, only `find . - type f ! - name /'md5_*' -execdir sh -c /`.  you need to run ALL 5 lines of it. just select it all and paste it into your shell.  or into a text editor and save it to a file.

Comment: Oh I have all of it. I just thought you specifically meant that one line. One moment.

Comment: you also seem to have a `/` before the `'md5_*'`.

Comment: Yes. I added that per googling other issues. I removed the sh {} + because shellscript check had given an error on that too.

Comment: and extra spaces where they shouldn't be.  first line of that should be `find . -type f ! -name 'md5_*' -execdir sh -c \`, **exactly** as in my answer above.

Comment: the `sh {} +` is required.  find can't pass args to an -exec program without either `{} +` or `{} \;`.  the `sh` before the `{}` is also required because when you run a shell with `-c`, you need to provide argument 0, a name for the process....otherwise the first arg from {} will be used as the process name.

Comment: Adding back in the last part of the line and fixing the spacing because... I have no idea what I was thinking and I'm back to just this which was probably the original error:
 line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
 line 5: `    for f; do'

Comment: the **entire** shell script from `for` to `done` has to be in single-quotes.  it's a script being passed to the `sh` interpreter via sh's `-c` option.   Again, **exactly** as it is in my answer.   It's wise to verify and google and sanity-check commands that random strangers give you on the internet - don't trust anyone - but verify doesn't mean break :)

Comment: the basic form is `find ... -exec sh -c 'single-quote-script-here' sh {} +`.   or with `-execdir` instead of `-exec` to change directories as required.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! Sorry for all the trouble!

Comment: BTW, the `sh -c '....script...' sh` thing is specific to `sh` (and bash and dash and other bourne-like shells) when using the shell's `-c` option.  It's not needed by most other programs.

Comment: is it working now?

Comment: Yeap Beautifully. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

This will find all files in a `/dir` and run `md5sum /dir/file`

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -print0 | xargs -0I{} md5sum {}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for `find`:

```bash
find /directory -type f -exec sh -c 'a={}; md5sum -- $a > $a.md5' \;
```